# The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

In my Android app I'm signing in via Firebase AuthUI using Google sign in. That part works. Now I tried to sign in using the `IdToken` but I always get this error message:

> com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException:
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Invalid id_token in IdP response: XXXXXXX... ]

This works and logs me in successfully in my Firebase project:

```
@OnClick(R.id.sign_in)
public void signIn() {
    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setTheme(getSelectedTheme())
                    .setLogo(getSelectedLogo())
                    .setAvailableProviders(getSelectedProviders())
                    .setTosAndPrivacyPolicyUrls(getSelectedTosUrl(),getSelectedPrivacyPolicyUrl())
                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(true,
                            true)
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

But trying to use `signInWithCredential` using credentials made from the `IdToken` gives me the error above:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        handleSignInResponse(resultCode, data);
        return;
    }

}

@MainThread
private void handleSignInResponse(int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();

        if(firebaseUser != null){

            auth.getCurrentUser().getIdToken(true).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {

                String idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                AuthCredential cred = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken ,null);

                auth.signInWithCredential(cred).addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> 
                        Log.v(TAG,"results: " + task1.getResult()));

            });
        }
    }
}
```

I'm following [this tutorial](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html) and my goal is to sign in to multiple Firebase projects.

Trying to sign in to a secondary Firebase project using the credentials from the IdToken above returns the same error.

```
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary");
FirebaseAuth.getInstance(app).signInWithCredential(credential);
```

Comment: check your date and time

Comment: You are a life saver, I had changed the date to test some scenarios but never bothered to revert it. I had been trying to implement sign in but always got malformed on the idtoken and finally your answer helped me to fill the gap. thanks

Answer (score 39):

I got this error when the time or time zone on the device was wrong.
Setting the correct time solved it.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. I was doing some testing with the device time settings. Didn't expect that it would mess up with my authentication.

Comment: Indeed, Check your timezone, restart your phone and it might actually fix it

Comment: Restarting the Emulator updated the time and fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to update the firebase auth plugin or google sign in plugin

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this while I was developing an App in Flutter. I have the proper timezone set on my device, yet I faced this issue.

The reason was due to an obvious mistake. I didn't add this to my info.plist

```
<!-- Put me in the [my_project]/ios/Runner/Info.plist file -->
<!-- Google Sign-in Section -->
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <!-- TODO Replace this value: -->
            <!-- Copied from GoogleService-Info.plist key REVERSED_CLIENT_ID -->
            <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.861823949799-vc35cprkp249096uujjn0vvnmcvjppkn</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<!-- End of the Google Sign-in Section -->
```

The official documentation link is [here](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in)