# The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired in react native fb login

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication

I want to make facebook login in my react native with firebase but after I integrate everything i got that error

```
[Error: [auth/invalid-credential] The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook: {"error":{"message":"(#100) The App_id in the input_token did not match the Viewing App","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AEYcUHj2aA0jqZQtrlGvmWA"}} ]]
```

I checked different solution but none of them help me . I recheck app id and secret in facebook developer and firebase console and both of them are same . what are the other possibilities in that case?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Changing the time and timezone worked for me [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63682399/11333898)

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting the emulator, it worked for me

Comment: Above + check your emulator timezone.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and after a while I discovered that with any change you made in the firebase application the configuration file can change.

So, try to download again `google-services.json` and replace the old one.

This worked for me.