# Can't sign in after signing out using Firebase Auth

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

If I create a user in Firestore Auth console and then login via app it's fine. However, if I create a user via my app, log out, and then attempt to login - it throws the following error and I'm not logged in.

Any help would be appreciated thank you. I'm not so familiar with Firebase. I have been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJHmhLGv-_0) tutorial.

**Error:**

> Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17004 "The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired., FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL}

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import Resolver

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil
    ) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
}

@main
struct quizApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            SetupView()
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentView**

```swift
import Resolver
import SwiftUI

extension Resolver: ResolverRegistering {
    public static func registerAllServices() {
        let model = AuthViewModel()

        register {
            model
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @InjectedObject var authViewModel: AuthViewModel

    var body: some View {
        if authViewModel.userSession != nil {
            AppTabView()
        } else {
            LoginView()
        }
    }
}
```

**RegistrationView**

```swift
import Resolver
import SwiftUI

struct RegisterView: View {
    @InjectedObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    @State var name: String = ""
    @State var email: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        List {
            TextField("Name", text: $name)
            TextField("Email", text: $email)
                .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                .textCase(.lowercase)
            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
            Spacer()
            Button("Sign Up") {
                Task {
                    try await viewModel.register(name: name, email: email, password: email)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Register")
    }
}
```

**LoginView**

```swift
import Resolver
import SwiftUI

struct LoginView: View {
    @InjectedObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    @State var email: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                TextField("Email", text: $email)
                    .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                    .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                    .textCase(.lowercase)
                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                Spacer()
                Button("Login") {
                    Task {
                        try await viewModel.login(email: email, password: password)
                    }
                }
                NavigationLink("Sign up") {
                    RegisterView()
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Login")
        }
    }
}
```

**AuthViewModel**

```swift
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import FirebaseFirestore

final class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userSession: FirebaseAuth.User?
    @Published var currentUser: User?

    init() {
        // Read from Firestore cache on device if logged in
        self.userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser
    }

    func login(email: String, password: String) async throws {
        do {
            let result = try await Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
            self.userSession = result.user
            try await fetch()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func register(name: String, email: String, password: String) async throws {
        do {
            let result = try await Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)
            self.userSession = result.user

            //
            let user = User(id: result.user.uid, name: name, jlptLevel: 5, email: email)
            let encodeUser = try Firestore.Encoder().encode(user)
            try await Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(user.id).setData(encodeUser)

            //
            try await fetch()
        } catch {
            print("Failed to create user", error)
        }
    }

    func signout() {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            self.userSession = nil
            self.currentUser = nil
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func deleteAccount() {
        if let session = self.userSession {
            session.delete()
            self.userSession = nil
            self.currentUser = nil
        }
    }

    func fetch() async throws {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let snapshot = try await Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).getDocument()
        self.currentUser = try snapshot.data(as: User.self)
    }
}
```

Comment: do you declare **only one** `@StateObject var viewModel = AuthViewModel()` in your view hierarchy and pass it using 
`.environmentObject(viewModel)` ?

Comment: Is the time on your device correct? [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59848069/the-supplied-auth-credential-is-malformed-or-has-expired)

Comment: I think the time is correct. Both simulators and my device have the issue @tomerpacific

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine, I did have only one state object yeah. Though I've since started using Resolver but I still do only have 1 instance passed around, which is why I'm confused